# Efficiently find array items where item.x > n and item.y < n

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic

(Example is Javascript, but the answers could to be language-agnostic).

I have a list of objects containing `from` and `to` fields:

```
const items = [
   { id: 1, from: 4, to: 10 },
   { id: 2, from: 1, to: 6  },
   { id: 2, from: 11, to: 20  },
];
```

I want to filter the list given a number `x` such that I get the elements where `from < x` and `to > x`. So:

```
fn(5, items) === [ 
   { id: 1, from: 4, to: 10 },
   { id: 2, from: 1, to: 6  },
];
```

Of course I can do that in *O(n)* with `Array.filter`:

```
function fn(x, list) {
   return list.filter(element => ( element.from < x) && (element.to > x));
}
```

But *O(n)* is bad news for me because the array could be long, and I need to repeat the query frequently.

How can I do this more efficiently? I don't mind an upfront overhead of indexing / sorting.

The best I've come up with is to make two sorted lists, one by `from` and the other by `to`. Binary-search both to create one list of elements where `from < x` and another list of elements where `from > x`, then get the intersection of those lists. But those lists could also be long, so the intersection part would be slow.

Comment: do you need to get the intervals themselves that contain _x_? If so, the best you can do anyway is _O(n)_ since in the worst case scenario you need to return all the intervals.

Comment: @JhonRayo99 I hope the example shows what I need? If the criterion was simply `< x` in a list of numbers, I could sort the numbers, find `x` or the closest number to it with a binary search, and return a slice of the list at that index. That's more efficient than `O(n)` yet the worst case scenario is that the whole list is `< x`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the complexity is still `O(n)`. So you can't do better in terms of asymptotic analysis. If you are certain most inputs won't cause this, you could use an interval tree. (in which case the complexity will be determined by the number of intervals in the result)

Comment: What is the maximum possible value for `from` and `to`? Is it countable?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya `from` and `to` range from 0 to infinity, but I know the maximum value of `x` so it would be trivial to cap them to that number.

Comment: @JhonRayo99 thanks for the phrase "Interval Tree", which after some reading, seems to be exactly what I was asking for (though not necessarily what I'll use - depending on stuff I measure with actual datasets -- it may be as good to just prepare a full flat map of points to intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the canonical data structure for this kind of query is an *Interval Tree*.

This is a binary tree with each node storing:

- A center point (*x*)
- A pointer to another node containing all intervals completely to the left of the center point (All elements where `to < x`)
- A pointer to another node containing all intervals completely to the right of the center point (All elements where `from > x`)
- All intervals overlapping the center point sorted by their beginning point
- All intervals overlapping the center point sorted by their ending point

To query, walk the tree:

- If the current node's centre point equals x, add the intervals in this node to the output, and stop
- Otherwise, collect the intervals in this node that apply to your query - using whichever sorted list applies, then walk the appropriate pointer.

It may also be used to find overlaps with another interval rather than just a point.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

A related structure, the segment tree, lends itself to more kinds of query.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of data structures that you can use for this with different performance characteristics.  You can use quadtrees, k-d trees, and so on.  In general they will be something like `O(k log(n) log(n))` where `k` is the number of points in the result set and `n` is the number of points in your data structure.

The idea behind all of them is that you're dividing the space horizontally and vertically until you get down to a size of 1.  That makes them `O(log(n))` to insert/delete.  But then your range search you walk the boxes until you get a box that is either all the way in your range, all the way out, or contains a single element (which you look at).